# External sql database access on windows phone.

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows-phone-8, ado.net

With regards to a windows phone 8 application, how can I write user input to an external SQL database and also read and display database query data on to the phone?

To be more specific, is there a file similar to a web.config where I could provide a connection string to access a database located on a server?

I would like to create an application where downloading the application and logging into an account will provide access to user data from any windows phone device.

Comment: Please don't connect directly from the phone to external DB. Make a call to some kind of server-side code for data exchange

Answer (score 2):

10,000 foot view looks something like this:

1. Your Windows Phone 8 app contains a reference to a web service.  Could be WCF, Web API, etc.  This will be hosted externally on whatever platform you decide to develop it with.
2. Your app will call methods defined in the web service to access the data.
3. That web service contains the data access code and may connect directly to the database.

So like Yuriy said...don't connect directly to an external database.  You need to develop a web service to do your data access and then consume the web service from your app.